# NTP server is running, but nothing can connect to it

Tags: ntp

I am trying to figure out why nothing can connect to my LAN NTP service running on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
$ ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 85.195.227.162  205.46.178.169   2 u  46m 273m    1  194.116    6.535   0.000
 time2.google.co .GOOG.           1 u  46m 273m    1   46.291   -4.626   0.000


$ service ntp status
● ntp.service - Network Time Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ntp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-07-09 18:35:37 PDT; 18s ago
     Docs: man:ntpd(8)
  Process: 21985 ExecStart=/usr/lib/ntp/ntp-systemd-wrapper (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 22005 (ntpd)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ntp.service
           └─22005 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 112:117

Jul 09 18:35:37  ntpd[22002]: Command line: /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 112:117
Jul 09 18:35:37  systemd[1]: Started Network Time Service.
Jul 09 18:35:37  ntpd[22005]: proto: precision = 0.054 usec (-24)
Jul 09 18:35:37  ntpd[22005]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123
Jul 09 18:35:37  ntpd[22005]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
Jul 09 18:35:37  ntpd[22005]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1:123
Jul 09 18:35:37  ntpd[22005]: Listen normally on 3 eno1 192.168.1.79:123
Jul 09 18:35:37  ntpd[22005]: Listen normally on 4 lo [::1]:123
Jul 09 18:35:37  ntpd[22005]: Listen normally on 5 eno1 [fe80::56bf:64ff:fe9c:487e%2]:123
Jul 09 18:35:37  ntpd[22005]: Listening on routing socket on fd #22 for interface updates


$ cat /etc/ntp.conf
#server time.google.com
server pool.ntp.org minpoll 14 maxpoll 16
server time.google.com minpoll 14 maxpoll 16
server ntp.research.gov minpoll 14 maxpoll 16
```

When I try to connect from local device I get Unable to connect (i am putting in local IP of the server).

On Windows I get "An error occured while Windows was synchronizing "

While on the same exact Windows machine if I run this in Powershell.. it seems to be able to connect?

```
> w32tm /stripchart /computer:192.168.1.79 /samples:3
Tracking 192.168.1.79 [192.168.1.79:123].
Collecting 3 samples.
The current time is 7/9/2020 6:41:13 PM.
18:41:13, d:+00.0006430s o:+00.6759665s  [                           | *                         ]
18:41:15, d:+00.0006612s o:+00.6760327s  [                           | *                         ]
18:41:17, d:+00.0006455s o:+00.6760841s  [                           | *                         ]
```

I do have firewall rule set as follows on the ubuntu server:

```
sudo ufw allow from any to any port 123 proto udp
```

EDIT: Little more info, one of the clients (wdmycloud) is reporting this error:

```
sntp[1065]: sock_cb: 192.168.1.79 not in sync, skipping this server
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after days of trying, of course once I give up and post on here in seek of help I stumble onto an answer.

Firewall rule needs to allow **out** as well

```
sudo ufw allow out from any to any port 123
```

also, in /etc/ntp.conf need to add **iburst** to each pool

```
$ cat /etc/ntp.conf
pool us.pool.ntp.org minpoll 14 maxpoll 16 iburst
server time.google.com minpoll 14 maxpoll 16 iburst
server ntp.research.gov minpoll 14 maxpoll 16 iburst
pool ntp.ubuntu.com minpoll 14 maxpoll 16 iburst
```

Comment: Setting minpoll and maxpoll like that is usually not a great idea - particularly not minpoll.  NTP will manage those things itself quite well, and the default values are chosen to be good compromises between accuracy & jitter.  NTP packets are so tiny and infrequent that you needn't be very concerned with bandwidth consumption.

Comment: The main reason I increased those was because when looking at my DNS log I saw constant requests for NTP servers in the log.

Comment: NTP polls won't generate DNS requests under normal circumstances.  They will only do so if one of your upstreams has started serving bad time and needs to be replaced.  The DNS requests are more likely coming from `systemd-timesyncd`, which you should disable if you're running `ntpd`.

Comment: understood, will remove mix/max poll and disable that and then check DNS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly allow NTP service in the firewall.

```
$ sudo ufw allow ntp
```

For help, visit the following link: [How to configure an NTP server and client on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://linuxways.net/ubuntu/how-to-configure-an-ntp-server-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-and-sync-a-clock/)